# Is it possible to embed ActiveX component in flash/flex?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, activex

I have an ActiveX componenet that displays some data from external systems (scada) and I'd like to embed it in my Flex web application's frontend (displayed in browser).

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to embed it in SWF directly but you can place it in the same HTML page.